# dynamic selectors added when a function is performed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am echoing some php lines with some class id and need to be able to use them with jquery .click as the selector. Is there a way to do this?? The property is not loaded with everthing else, it is added later on by php.

play.js-

```
$(".link").click( function(){
   /* var l = ""
     $.post('input_commands/move_to.php',{l:l}, function(data) {
      text=data;
      elem = $("#placeholder");
      //delay=100;
      addTextByDelay(text,elem,delay);
   }); */
   alert("omg whyyyyy");
});
```

get_locations.php -

```
if($array_loc['loc_north']>0){echo "<a class='link' id='location_north'>Go north to ".$array_loc_north['loc_name']."</a> <br>";}
```

Comment: So you are asking how jquery can reference or call data from your php file, on click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a delegated event because your elements are added to the DOM dynamically (or after the event handler is created).

```
$(document).on('click', '.link', function(){
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

In the above, the event is delegated to the document and so all clicks will be checked against the `.link` selector, even if the target is an element that didn't exist when the event was delegated.

Answer (score 0):

in order to bind an event to a dynamic element (one that was added after first DOM load),

replace:

```
$(".link").click( function(){
```

with:

```
$(document).on('click', '.link', function(){
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If it's added dynamically using ajax you might want to call that selector and append the .click() on the callback.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '...',
        success: function(response) {
            // do stuff with response (assume that .link will be appended)
            $(".link").click( function(){
                //stuff when click link
            }
        }
    });
```

Otherwise, you can output the links with the onclick attribute and define a custom function:

```
if($array_loc['loc_north']>0){echo "<a class='link' id='location_north' onclick='customFunction(this)'>Go north to ".$array_loc_north['loc_name']."</a> <br>";}
```

and in the JS:

```
function customFunction(element) {
 //do stuff here after the link was clicked
 //element variable passed as parameter contains the link element clicked
}
```

PS: If there are multiple elements it's not ok to specify constant value for "id" attribute because it should be **unique**.